# Log4View UDP Message Structure

Tags: udp, log4view

I'm trying to send from various applications logs to `Log4View` by `UDP` (port 878), but i can't find any information of the message format on the web.

I've tried to send a simple string but it won't work at all.

Is there any information about it? I know that it is very simple task in C# with `log4net`, but the web is lack of information on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

To send log messages to Log4View via UDP, you have to use the xml format.
You can find more in our documentation about how to use the xml format:

http://www.log4view.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Log4ViewHelp/XML_Layout.html

Yours sincerely

Philipp Lauchner

**PROSA GmbH**
Development & Support

Comment: don't advertise you company in comments or answers, this can result in marking post as spam...